# ComboBox on returning only one Item c#

Tags: c#

I am Selecting data from a database using SQL commands, I want to select data from a table to be read in a combox but it seems the combox only displays one item instead of all Items in that particular column.

Here is my sql statement:

```
public void SelectEmployee()
        {

            Query = "SELECT Employee_Name FROM TblEmployees";
            reader = conn.ExecuteStatement(Query);
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                ComboBox1.Text = reader["Employee_Name"].ToString();

            }

            conn.CloseConnection();

        }
```

This runs smoothly , the comboBox only shows one name though instead of 10 names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You loop over the reader but continue to assign to the combo Text property the current value of the reader, thus overwriting the previous assignment.

Instead, add every value of the column `Employee_Name` to the `Items` collection where they will be displayed in the dropdown list of the combox and the user can select them

```
    public void SelectEmployee()
    {
        Query = "SELECT Employee_Name FROM TblEmployees";
        reader = conn.ExecuteStatement(Query);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(reader["Employee_Name"].ToString());
        }
        conn.CloseConnection();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know exactly what `ExecuteStatement` do exactly but with this `while` loop, you only set the **last** value of `Employee_Name` column to `.Text` property.

You can add as `Items` instead of assing it's `.Text` property like;

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(reader["Employee_Name"].ToString());
}
```